# the method is undefined for the type java

Tags: java, accessor

I have tried everything and eclipse keeps returning the error "The method getX() is undefined for the type Point". Here is the code this error comes up on:

```
public class Rectangle {
 double Height;
 double Width;//Variables for the class
 double x;
 double y;
 public Rectangle(Point p, double width, double height) {
    this.Height = height;
    this.Width = width;
    this.x = p.getX();
    this.y = p.getY();
 }
}
```

This class and the class point

```
public class Point {
 double x;
 double y;
 public Point(double x, double y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
 }
 public double getX() {
     return this.x;
 }
 public double getY() {
    return this.y;
 }
}
```

Whenever I call one of point's accessors, I get the error, I saw somewhere that you are supposed use the keyword new every time you call upon an accessor but it hasn't worked for me in this case.

SIDENOTE: I am very new to this language and to programming overall so if you could keep things simple it would be great, thank you!

Comment: Are you certain you are using your class `Point` and not [`java.awt.Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html)? Or something else named `Point`? Have you done a `clean` build?

Comment: Are you importing/using the correct `Point` class?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch AWT Point has `getX` and `getY` though. Could still be an import error.

Comment: The code as you have shown it is fine (See [Ideone](http://ideone.com/O4yClG)). We need to see a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces this to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean your project, refresh your IDE and build the project again